# What is the official linux subsystem mailing list for questions about cgroups and possible bugs thereof?

Tags: linux

Recently I have stumbled upon something I think could be a bug in some version of Linux kernel/cgroup. I have already posted the [original question](https://superuser.com/questions/1367228/how-is-cgroups-memory-limit-in-bytes-related-to-rss) on SuperUser and that had no results. But I am having a hard time figuring out where the official channel for Linux Control Group related bugs, questions, etc. can be found. Does somebody have any idea?

Comment: You would be better off filing a bug report with the Linux distribution that you are using.  Your original post is lacking in specifics, and likely to be ignored by a mailing list.

Comment: As far as the down votes and off-topic label goes, I think this is a useful question even for administrators. The Linux maintainer landscape is some what of a jungle for the uninitiated and knowing how and where to report bugs is a very real software related issue that can help administrators a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary source for "ownership" of Linux kernel components is the [MAINTAINERS](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/MAINTAINERS#n3766) file. (At least for the time being – there are plans to split it up into several files.)

It lists `cgroups@vger.kernel.org` as the mailing list for control groups.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remove the question since the moderators consider it to be a an off-topic question. But this is very useful for me. I couldn't easily find any hints of an authoritative list of maintainers/contact points.